# Cannot add new package to laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm currently working on an old project created by different developers. But when I'm adding a new package to `composer.json` file, it returns a lot of errors. Please see my code and screenshot below.

**Package I'm trying to add**

`"aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"`

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
     "aceraven777/laravel-paymaya": "^1.0",
     "aloha/twilio": "^4.0",
     "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
     "florianv/laravel-swap": "^1.3",
     "freshbitsweb/laratables": "^1.1",
     "intervention/image": "^2.4",
     "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
     "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
     "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
     "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
     "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
     "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.13",
     "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
     "php-http/message": "^1.7",
     "stevebauman/location": "^3.0",
     "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop",
     "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "2.0.*",
     "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0"
    }
```

**Errors in command prompt**
[image]

Comment: Please share the error message in text form, not as an image. Additionally, explain how you did add that package - in the image, you run `composer install` which uses `composer.lock`  and not any new package

Answer (score 1):

Remove the package from composer.json and use `composer require aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel`.

The thing is that when you run `composer install` it uses `composer.lock`, but it isn't synced with `composer.json`. `composer update` probably will work, but isn't good approach.

Comment: Uhm, running `composer update` will also update other packages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's no error. These are some warnings and somehow when you want to install your package, package name was added to your composer.json but not download. You can remove that package manually or by composer remove YOUR_PACAKGE. 
Then again install that package.

Comment: How can I do that? Could you please add it to your answer? :)

Comment: `composer remove aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel`

Comment: I think it's not yet installed, since when I run `composer show`, it's not showing on the list.

Comment: Do one thing remove `composer.lock` file and `vendor` folder also after that run `composer update` command for some deprecated package dependency then install your new package.